# CakePHP 3.x to 4.x upgrade tool: composer errors "could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an old CakePHP 3.8.13 application which I want to upgrade to CakePHP 4.

Currently this is in the CakePHP 3 `composer.json`. It is deployed in an environment running PHP 7.2.

I am also running PHP 7.2 locally, which is where I'm trying to perform the upgrade.

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.8.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "^2.0.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cakephp/bake": "^1.9.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "^3.0",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "^3.17.0",
        "josegonzalez/dotenv": "3.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5|^6",
        "psy/psysh": "@stable"
    },
```

When I go through the [Upgrade Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/appendices/4-0-upgrade-guide.html) it works up until the last step. This is what I've done so far. The quoted sections are from the guide linked above.

> The upgrade tool only works on applications running on latest CakePHP 3.x.

Changed `composer.json` so it has this, which I believe will get the latest CakePHP 3.x

```
"require": {
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.*",
```

Followed by `composer update`. This works without errors and when inspecting the file in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` is does appear to have gone from 3.8.13 to 3.10.5

> If you are not running on PHP 7.2 or higher, you will need to upgrade PHP before updating CakePHP.

We are running PHP 7.2 so this is fine:

```
% php -v
PHP 7.2.34 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2023 06:18:05) ( NTS )
```

> Install the upgrade tool...

All of this works without errors:

```
git clone https://github.com/cakephp/upgrade
cd upgrade
git checkout 4.x
composer install --no-dev
```

Use the upgrade tool. Again this works fine and changes the file locations appropriately within my app directory:

```
# Rename locale files
bin/cake upgrade file_rename locales ../path/to/my/app

# Rename template files
bin/cake upgrade file_rename templates ../path/to/my/app
```

> Applying Rector Refactorings ... to automatically fix many deprecated CakePHP and PHPUnit method calls. It is important to apply rector before you upgrade your dependencies

These commands work fine:

```
bin/cake upgrade rector --rules phpunit80 ../path/to/my/app/tests
bin/cake upgrade rector --rules cakephp40 ../path/to/my/app/src
```

> Update CakePHP Dependency
> After applying rector refactorings, upgrade CakePHP and PHPUnit with the following composer commands:

The first command to upgrade PHPUnit works without error

```
composer require --dev --update-with-dependencies "phpunit/phpunit:^8.0"
```

### It fails here:

The next command, which AFAIK updates CakePHP from 3.x to 4.x, fails:

```
composer.phar require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:4.0.*"
```

Output is

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/cakephp 4.0.*, found cakephp/cakephp[4.0.0, ..., 4.0.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 2
    - cakephp/bake is locked to version 1.12.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - cakephp/bake 1.12.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.8.0 -> found cakephp/cakephp[3.8.0, ..., 3.10.5] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (4.0.*).
  Problem 3
    - cakephp/debug_kit is locked to version 3.23.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - cakephp/debug_kit 3.23.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.7.0 -> found cakephp/cakephp[3.7.0, ..., 3.10.5] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (4.0.*).
```

I don't understand this because surely the point of this last command is to update it from 3.x to 4.x. If it's being run with the `--update-with-dependencies` flag then should it not update the dependencies as well?

It seems like the error messages are telling me it can't install 4.x *because of* the dependencies like `cakephp/bake` and `cakephp/debug_kit`.

Why does this occur and how can I resolve it?

For reference the `composer.json` - after the steps above - looks like this

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "cakephp/cakephp": "3.*",
    "cakephp/migrations": "^2.0.0",
    "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*",
},
"require-dev": {
    "cakephp/bake": "^1.9.0",
    "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "^3.0",
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "^3.17.0",
    "josegonzalez/dotenv": "3.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
    "psy/psysh": "@stable"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--update-with-dependencies` only updates the dependencies of the packages that you are requiring (unless they are also root dependencies), so only dependencies of `phpunit/phpunit` and `cakephp/cakephp` will be updated.

The versions of `cakephp/bake` and `cakephp/debug_kit` that you are currently requiring in your root composer file, are not compatible with CakePHP `4.0.x`, that's what composer is saying. You have to update all of these root dependencies manually to require compatible versions accordingly.

You can refer to [**the corresponding app template**](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.0.4/composer.json) of the CakePHP version that you're upgrading to (make sure to do this for every upgrade step, even for the minor version ones, and while you're there, make sure to adjust the files in `config` accordingly too).

From the latest `4.0.x` app template:

`require`

```json
"cakephp/migrations": "^3.0@beta",
"cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.2",
"mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8"
```

`require-dev`

```json
"cakephp/bake": "^2.0.3",
"cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "~4.1.0",
"cakephp/debug_kit": "^4.0",
"josegonzalez/dotenv": "^3.2",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
"psy/psysh": "@stable"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I also had to remove my lock file, edit the composer.json manually (including updating Cake to 4.0.*) and then composer update to finish.